# Extract data from multiple fragments from single button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am making a contact app. It has three fragments, scrollview, that has edit texts. Also the activity has one save button in menu item. I wanna to save the data of all three fragments by just that single save button. My UI looks something like this

[image: Add Records One Fragment]

How can I extract data from all three fragments to my container activity.

This is my code of Menu Item SAVE in Container Activity

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.discard :
            break;
        case R.id.save:
            Personal_Details p1 = new Personal_Details();
            Proffesional_Details p2 = new Proffesional_Details();
            Social s = new Social();
            Person p = new Person(p1.getName(),p1.getLastName(),p1.getPhone(),p1.getEmail(),p1.getDOB(),
                    p2.getCName(),p2.getTitle(),p2.getIM(),p2.getwebsite(),p2.getOfficeA(),
                    s.getNickName(),s.getIntro(),s.getFb(),s.getTwitter(),s.getInsta());
            dbHelper Database = new dbHelper(this,null,null,1);
            Database.addPerson(p);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

This is my code in one of the three identical fragments PERSONAL_DETAILS :

```
public class Personal_Details extends Fragment {

EditText name, lastname, phoneNumber,email,dob;
public Personal_Details() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal__details, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    name= (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
    lastname= (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    phoneNumber= (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
    email= (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
    dob= (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.DOB);
}

public String getName(){
    if(name.getText().toString()!=null)
        return name.getText().toString();
    else
        return "";
}

public String getLastName(){
    if(lastname.getText().toString()!=null)
        return lastname.getText().toString();
    else
        return "";
}

public String getEmail(){
    if(email.getText().toString()!=null)
        return email.getText().toString();
    else
        return "";
}

public String getPhone(){
    if(phoneNumber.getText().toString()!=null)
        return phoneNumber.getText().toString();
    else
        return "";
}

public String getDOB(){
    if(dob.getText().toString()!=null)
        return dob.getText().toString();
    else
        return "";
}
}
```

How can I save the info from these fragments to My Container Activity by Save Button?

EDIT : Here is my Adapter for Scroll View

`class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

```
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Personal_Details();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Proffesional_Details();
            break;
        case 2 :
            fragment = new Social();
            break;
        default:break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0 : return "Personal";
        case 1 : return "Professional";
        case 2 : return "Social";
        default:return null ;
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Well, you can find fragments by `FragmentManager` and call necessary methods. Or i missed something?

Comment: Calling from FragmentManager requires IDs. While making scrollview from ViewPager and FragmentStatePageAdapter it doesn't require the ids. @PetrovDmitrii

Comment: How can I give IDs to fragments then! I edited the question and put the container activity there @PetrovDmitrii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all your `Fragment`s from the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and call the getter methods from them. You can save references to the `Fragment`s in your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in `instantiateItem` method and remove them in `destroyItem` method.

Example code -

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(...); 
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public List<Fragment> getAllFragments() {
        List<Fragment> list = new List<Fragment>();

        for(int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++) {
           int key = sparseArray.keyAt(i);
           // get the object by the key.
           list.add(sparseArray.get(key));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: ohk thanks! And how to refer to the fragment classes from this list!!

Comment: Hope you figured it out? You can just use `instanceof`.